# Delphi Xe2 licensing

Tags: delphi, licensing, delphi-xe2

I look to buy Delphi Xe2 Pro. I am alone to use it and I have 2 PC : one in the office, and one portable for working 'on the road'. 
The Delphi Xe2 licenses are not very clear, so is there any way to buy only one license for the 2 PC because I **never** develop on the 2 PC at the same time.

The important (may be) information is that, when 'on the road', I not always have an Internet connection.

Comment: Ask whoever sells that software.

Comment: Second that, is it a clearly a question for the sales dept.

Comment: Single named user licence will be fine for you

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. AFAIK questions about licensing software development tools are on topic here, and the "sales people" don't always know what they're selling. Sales recommended me the wrong Delphi license once. Embarcadero's web site only helps to confirm what you've found from other sources, it's not properly structured to aid with this kind of queries.

Comment: OK... I yet ask to 'sales people' but without any answer. And I did'nt see any place where my case is clearly explained.

Comment: @David : thank you for the answer : it was not very clear...

Comment: I actually got *sold* the wrong license. I wanted RAD Studio, got Delphi alone. Since I was on a hurry (and didn't have the extra money) I just had to move on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that it may be different depending on who you ask at Embarcadero support.

Below is a reply I got from Embarcadero support, which doesn't make sense because it's a *named user license* and not a *workstation serial number*:

> Workstation serial numbers are issued with a limit to a single
>   workstation registration.

The license types are either a named user license, or a floating license with a license server (more expensive).

So, regardless of whether Embarcadero support says that the serial number is for a single computer, for a named license, they give you 5 activations per license before you have to contact them to reset it.

Here's how you can check your activations. Visit this URL, but replace serialnumber with your serial number and regkey with your registration key:

```
https://reg.codegear.com/srs6/activation.do?x=1&serialNumber=serialnumber&key=regkey&viewType=1
```

The registration key is the part your computer generates. Every registration key is another computer/activation.

Answer (score 5):

Very good answer by the famous Bob Swart : [on EDN forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63577&tstart=0)